# Hide keyboard when searchBarSearchButtonClicked

Tags: search, keyboard, hide

How to hide keyboard immediately in search bar search button clicked delegate?

Following code snippest not working:

```
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar 
{ 
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write the code from where you want to hide the keyboard.

`[self.view endEditing:YES]`;

Thats it..

Comment: In my case it was `[searchBar endEditing:YES];` inside of the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` method.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the delegate?

```
[mySearchBarName setDelegate: self];
```

and also include this in your @interface

```
UISearchBarDelegate
```